# android multiple themes, one app

Tags: android, android-theme

I need to develop an app, which can for some users (defined by server) set different app colors. 
I have read a lot of custom theme with usage of attr.xml file, but android studio builder will be broken if I would use it.
So i have developed another approach - I subclassed Resorses class of my BaseActivity:

```
  CustomResource customResource;

@Override
public Resources getResources() {
    if (customResource == null) {
        customResource = new CustomResource(super.getAssets(), super.getResources().getDisplayMetrics(), super
                .getResources().getConfiguration());
    }

    return customResource;
}

public class CustomResource extends Resources {

    public CustomResource(AssetManager assets, DisplayMetrics metrics, Configuration config) {
        super(assets, metrics, config);

    }

    @Override
    public int getColor(int id) throws NotFoundException {
        Log.d("TAG", "id: " + id + "   getResourceName: " + getResourceName(id));
        Log.i("TAG", "Came Color: "+super.getColor(id));
        return getColor ( getResourceName(id) , id);
    }

    public int getColor(String aString, int oldId) {
        String packageName = getPackageName();
        int resId = getIdentifier(getThemeColorName(aString),null,null);
        Log.v("TAG", "resId: "+resId);
        if (resId != 0) {
            Log.i("TAG", "We SET Color: "+super.getColor(resId));
            return super.getColor(resId);
        } else {
            return super.getColor(oldId);
        }
    }

    private String getThemeColorName(String aString){
        int pos = aString.lastIndexOf('/');
        if (pos != -1){
            aString = aString.substring(0, pos+1) + "b" + aString.substring(pos+1, aString.length());
        }

        Log.d("TAG", "aString NOW: " + aString);

        return aString;
    }

}
```

And retreive appropriet resource (just for testing, I am pulling out instead of "someColor" -> "bsomeColor".
As I look into log, everything is working, colors are being changing.

But if I set colors from xml (activities layout) I see all methods are being exected (sucessfully), but on my screen android epplyies colors without "b" prefix (BUT all my methods are being called - getColor() for every view, and I return super.getColor for an appropriate color, what I need!

Please, give me ideas how this can be solved, or give me other options to nicely introduce multiple themes, not breaking the xml editor

Comment: Have you looked at this answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811594/implementing-user-choice-of-theme

Comment: @sparkysword my question is anout how to manage custom colors - like firmColor1, ets, not android part. That question is about other stuff

Comment: How are you defining "bsomeColor"? Is it a hex number or a color.fromrgb?

Comment: @sparkysword nothing special :  
<color name="bviolet">#e10000</color>
 <color name="violet">#7829ff</color>