# How to apply themed resources to multiple themes?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

A user-selectable theme (light and dark), with each theme having its own resources, is [straightforward to implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811594/implementing-user-choice-of-theme) if a single parent theme is used in the app:

```
<style name="MyApp.Dark" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <item name="themeBackground">@color/dark_grey</item>
    <item name="themeBackgroundTransparent">@color/darkColorBackgroundTransparent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/darkColorPrimary</item>
    .
    .
</style>

<style name="MyApp.Light" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="themeBackground">@color/brown_50</item>
    <item name="themeBackgroundTransparent">@color/lightColorBackgroundTransparent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/lightColorPrimary</item>
    .
    .
</style>
```

However, a typical Android app might employ multiple parent themes throughout the app such as the dialog theme, no action bar theme, or dialog-when-large theme. These themes would not be covered by current themes extending `Theme.Material` (*because inheritance is expensive*), so using these themes would *necessitate* additional style definitions for light and dark themes:

```
<style name="MyApp.DialogWhenLarge.Light" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge">
</style>

<style name="MyApp.DialogWhenLarge.Dark" parent="android:Theme.Material.DialogWhenLarge">
</style>
```

In order to apply themed resources to the *new* themes, the trivial solution is to copy and paste individual items from the `MyApp.Dark` theme into the new `MyApp.DialogWhenLarge.Dark` theme, et al, but the amount of duplicated code becomes unmanageable, incomprehensible, and error-prone with increasing numbers of themes and resources.

**So my question is, what is a simple way to apply themed resources to multiple theme definitions?**

Ideally, one would be able to apply a set of resources to a theme in the same way one would applies a style to a view, which would result in a solution of the following form:

```
<style name="MyApp.DialogWhenLarge.Light" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge">
    <item name="themedResources">[pointer to canonical list of light theme resources]
</style>
```

Of course, it is also important that any solution retains the ability to reference themed resources from views in the format of `?themeBackground`