# How to change whole app theme dynamically in android

Tags: android

I want to change the theme for the whole app(all activities of the app) when user choose a theme from options and save the chosen theme. So that when user opens the app for next time, he/she can see the changed theme. How can i do this?

Comment: If I understand correctly, this was raised and answered earlier - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811594/implementing-user-choice-of-theme Another detailed example - http://www.hidroh.com/2015/02/16/support-multiple-themes-android-app/

Answer (score 1):

Create a base Activity for your app and override onCreate to set the theme.

More details check : http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html

Answer (score 0):

from manifest file

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your ***`AppTheme`*** parent in ***`styles.xml`***. *AppTheme* is the default theme for your application, so changing it would change application theme.