# Change Spinner Colors Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, material-design

I'm in Android Studio and I've set a spinner like this:

```
<com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner
        android:id="@+id/android_material_design_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Material Design Spinner"
        android:textColorHint="#05ab9a"
        app:met_floatingLabel="normal" />
```

It is taken from [this](http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/02/android-material-design-spinner-dropdown-example.html) site

It works properly, but I just can't change the colors. I need to change:
- Hint color
- The background color of the panel that is shown when you click on the spinner
- The color of the little arrow to click

I also have an error for the last line: "unknown attribute app:met_floatingLabel", is it related to my gradle build?
Here it is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myname.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
compile 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
compile 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library:1.1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

Full xml [here](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AniEkQ5k9-XDnG6JlXRI8BVry09h)

Sorry for the horrible layout of the code

**//EDIT**
I don't know if it's clear, but I mean that even if I change the colors in the xml fil, it doesn't apply them in the layout

Comment: Can you include the full xml file with the spinner in it?

Comment: Sure, I'm modifying @IsaacPayne

Comment: Don, I added a link because I had problems adding the code @IsaacPayne

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MaterialBetterSpinner](https://github.com/Lesilva/BetterSpinner) is using the styling from [MaterialEditText](https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText/wiki) (the linked documentation has a lot of other visual fiddling you can try), for basic color editing, use:

```
app:met_baseColor="#0056d3"
app:met_primaryColor="#982360"
app:met_errorColor="#ddaa00"
```

To get the app namespace and resolve the error you mentioned, use `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in parent viewgroup.

Comment: Awesome! Just one last question: how can I make the color changing when the theme changes? (The user is able to change the theme) @Lyla

Comment: The only problem is that the colors are darker, how can I solve it?

Comment: Hmm, that sounds a bit more complicated - you'll need to reference theme colors instead of hard coded values, so something like `"@color/primary"`. As far as how to swap themes at runtime, this post talks about allowing users to change the theme from preferences - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811594/implementing-user-choice-of-theme --- as far as fiddling with colors and getting the correct colors you want, I'd read over the [MaterialEditText](https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText/wiki) - I'm not familiar with the library, I just looked at the source code/docs for a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to your Scrollview in your layout should stop the error.

e.g

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you, how can I change the colors?