# changing a Drawable xml using java

Tags: java, android, drawable

In my app I have a few buttons and they are all assigned to the same drawable xml shape. I want the user to be able to customize this shape from a few different xml files.

I'm trying to make it as a reward system for watching adverts with in the app. I've set a reward ad up and when it is played all the way through it counts and sends that number to my database. when it gets to 5 I want the option to change the button drawable which is called buttonbackground.xml to buttonbackground2 but in all my activities that use the same drawable. would it be possible to write the code in a separate activity called customize in which it changes all activities?

also would it need to be a shared pref to make it permanent?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Yes, a sharedpref, or a pref would be needed to keep the change. Maybe you could use the theme functionality. How much java do you know?

Comment: im ok with java , and i use google as a reference for things im unsure of. but i stumped with where to start with this to be honest @StephanBranczyk

Comment: Try using android themes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811594/implementing-user-choice-of-theme

Comment: thanks @Stephan Branczyk