# Change Theme with preference

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-theme

I've tried the answer in [Implementing user choice of theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811594/implementing-user-choice-of-theme), but it didn't work for me.

There's a listpreference in my settings which let the user choose between light or dark theme. What should I do? Here's my OnPreferenceChangeListener in SettingsACtivity, which I learned from the internet.

```
private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener themelistener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        String stringValue = newValue.toString();

        if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {   //set ListPreference summary
            ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
            int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
            preference.setSummary(
                    index >= 0
                            ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]
                            : null);

            if (index == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(thisActivity, "Dark" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();MainActivity.reloadTheme();     //if done toast will be deleted
            } else if (index == 1){Toast.makeText(thisActivity, "Light" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();MainActivity.reloadTheme();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
    ;
};
```

**EDIT:**
My MainActivity snippet with problem, it couldn't resolve themeId

```
public static void reloadTheme()
{
    int index = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(thisActivity).getInt("index", 0);
    if(index == 0){  //couldn't resolve themeId
        themeId = R.style.OwnDark; 
    }
    else if(index == 1){
        themeId = R.style.OwnLight;
    }
}
```

Comment: In what way did the answer you reference not work?

Comment: You should be able to combine that answer with your current code, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I've updated my question. If you need more information, just ask

Comment: You haven't posted enough to show *why* the call to`getDefaultPreference` fails. And is it actually failing, or is 0 the actual value of the preference?

Comment: entry values in arrays.xml are only 0 and 1. What do I miss, should I post the whole thing?