# Change app theme color according to the API response in Android

Tags: android, android-theme, androiddesignsupport, android-color

Get the Color from API response and save it in Shared Preferences. Later create a singleton class called Theme.

Get the instance of the Theme class where you need and get the color from the singleton class.

set the color programmatically to any views.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing user choice of theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811594/implementing-user-choice-of-theme)

Comment: Not user changing the theme. Theme color code are from the Response

Answer (score 1):

if you change textview color used below code..

```
text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

and if you want to change app theme color then used below code...

```
            setTheme(R.style.ThemeApp_Green); // themApp_green value define style.xml file.
```