# Inverting the screen colors in my app - how to?

Tags: java, android

I want to invert colors when the user enables nightmode feature in my app, it’s like when enabling inverted colors option on the system settings but I want it to be an option only in my app.

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Implement multiple themes for your app and allow user to choose between them. Look here: [Implementing user choice of theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811594/implementing-user-choice-of-theme) - define day and night theme.

Smarter, but more difficult way is to calculate opposing colors at runtime and set them dynamically, in this case you will be never sure what is final effect though